# Uniqueness of the Solution to Fredholm's Integral Equations of the First Kind

Tags: integration, integral-equations

Any one who knows the conditions for Uniqueness of the Solution to Fredholm's Integral Equations of the First Kind?

Thanks.

Comment: Since Fredholm integral operators tend to be compact (for example if considered as operators $L^2 \to L^2$), I think uniqueness would be rather rare

Comment: @user38355, this is a gap for me. Any references you’d recommend?

Comment: Asanov (2019) ["About Uniqueness of Solutions of Fredholm Linear Integral Equations of the First Kind in the Axis"](https://www.pmf.ni.ac.rs/filomat-content/2019/33-5/33-5-6-8814.pdf) for a general characterisation, Han (2015) ["The necessary and sufficient condition for the existence and uniqueness of a system of Fredholm integral equations of the first kind"](https://www.sciengine.com/SSM/doi/10.1360/N012014-00189) in Chinese for determining uniqueness in a specific case of Laplace's equation.

Comment: See, for example, https://www.colorado.edu/amath/sites/default/files/attached-files/fredholm.pdf