# Uniqueness of homogeneous Fredholm equation of the first kind

Tags: integral-equations

Suppose $K(x,t)$ is known and
$$
\int f(x)K(x,t)dx=0
$$
Are there some known sufficient and \ or necessary conditions on $K(x,t)$ such that the only solution is $f(x)=0$ a.s.? ($f$ can be in a space of your choice but to keep things concrete say $f \in \mathcal{L}^p$)

I've been searching around for some answers to this question but the questions are usually unanswered and / or uniqueness is rare (e.g. [Uniqueness of the Solution to Fredholm's Integral Equations of the First Kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251909/uniqueness-of-the-solution-to-fredholms-integral-equations-of-the-first-kind) and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873278/existence-of-solution-of-volterra-integral-equation-of-the-first-kind). Are there some known results or is this type of problem very much a case-by-case type of issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Sufficient condition:**  given $\phi\in C_0^\infty(a,b)$ there exists $t_0$ such that $K(x,t_0)=\phi(x)$ almost everywhere.

Under the above condition, the unique locally integrable solution of the homogeneous Fredholm equation of the first kind is the zero function.

*Proof:* We have
$$\int_a^bf(x)\phi(x)\;dx=\int_a^bf(x)K(x,t_0)\;dx=0,\quad \forall\ \phi\in C_0^\infty(a,b).$$
It follows from the [du Bois-Reymond lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations#The_du_Bois-Reymond_lemma) that $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere.